# Can ionized air be used to create airflow without fans or other moving parts?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, cooling, ionization-energy

If I understand it correctly, ionized air should produce an electromagnetic field, which should mean that it can be attracted/reppeled by another field of the oposite/same charge respectively.

If so, can this effect be utilized to create a steady airflow, for example, in a CPU cooler? Would the charge just strong enough to move air out of the radiator interfere with electronics around it?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about using it to cooling a CPU, but this is a product you actually can buy:

https://www.sharperimage.com/view/product/Ionic+Comfort+Quadra+Air+Purifier/201114

It has no moving parts, but when you switch it on, it moves air. Not like a fan: The flow is weak, but it is strong enough that you can feel it.

The main purpose of the product above, which may be a *detriment* if you wanted to use the same phenomenon for cooling electronics is, it collects fine particulates.  When you use the product, you have to pull the electrodes out every week or so for cleaning. Where I live (urban area) they turn black with soot.

Answer (score 2):

50 years ago, a couple of engineers built a miniature "flying platform" which had a set of electrodes on top that ionized air molecules, and an oppositely-charged porous grid below that attracted the ions. Most of the ions zoomed right through the grid, headed down towards the floor of their lab. This setup imparted a momentum change to a small flow of air and thereby generated enough lift to support the little device against gravity, causing it to hover.

The catch: they had a separate high voltage power supply on the lab bench which fed electrical power to the platform through a very thin wire. This made it possible for the feeble lift generated by the platform to be enough to hover it.